# Selecting XML nodes using LINQ

Tags: .net, xml, linq

I am trying to select out the "publishInformation" node, (specifically the "Publish_Date" value) from the following xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
    <sdnList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <publshInformation>
        <Publish_Date>04/06/2018</Publish_Date>
        <Record_Count>6297</Record_Count>
    </publshInformation>
    <sdnEntry>
        <uid>36</uid>
        <lastName>TestLastName</lastName>
        <sdnType>Entity</sdnType>
        <addressList>
          <address>
             <uid>25</uid>
             <city>TestCity</city>
             <country>TestCountry</country>
          </address>
        </addressList>
    </sdnEntry>
    </sdnList>
```

All of my attempts get null results and I am not sure what I am missing. Below is my most recent attempt.

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(model.InputStream);
XElement publishInformation = root.Descendants("sdnList")
                    .Descendants("publshInformation")
                    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Using JohnyL's suggestion the code is below.

```
string xmlstring;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(model.OfacXml.InputStream))
{
    xmlstring = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlstring);
var dates = xml.Elements("publshInformation").Select(pi => 
    pi.Element("Publish_Date").Value);
```

I am still getting null in dates with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var text = 
    @"<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
        <sdnList xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
            <publshInformation>
                <Publish_Date>04/06/2018</Publish_Date>
                <Record_Count>6297</Record_Count>
            </publshInformation>
            <sdnEntry>
                <uid>36</uid>
                <lastName>TestLastName</lastName>
                <sdnType>Entity</sdnType>
                <addressList>
                    <address>
                        <uid>25</uid>
                        <city>TestCity</city>
                        <country>TestCountry</country>
                    </address>
                </addressList>
            </sdnEntry>
        </sdnList>";

var xml = XElement.Parse(text);
var dates = xml.Elements("publshInformation").Select(pi => pi.Element("Publish_Date").Value);
dates.ToList().ForEach(WriteLine);
```

If you'd like to use `XDocument` instead of `XElement`:

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(text);
var dates = xml.Element("sdnList")
               .Elements("publshInformation")
               .Select(pi => pi.Element("Publish_Date").Value);
```

Comment: I am still getting a null using XElement and an object instance error when using XDocument. I added the sample code to my question.

Comment: I did. My model contains an InputStream and I am converting it to a string before running exactly what you wrote. When I debug, I can see the entire document just fine in the var xml, but for some reason, returns after that are null.

Comment: Did you cut off some namespace?

Comment: Okay I may be zeroing in on the issue. I have been passing the input stream to my business layer and then trying to take apart the file. I tried putting your code, as well as a few filed tries of my own back into the Controller and it worked. I don't understand. I can see the data in the business layer but can't select it? Also, there were no errors and the references in my project all worked as expected. Am I missing a reference that doesn't trigger an error?

Comment: @joerdie It's hard to say without seeing what's going on in your code. If you have this XML as string, there's no problem to parse it with `XDocument.Parse` or `XElement.Parse`. If you have a [Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream),  you can use, then, `XDocument.Load` or `XElement.Load`.

Comment: I agree. For now, I will mark your answer as correct as the code is the correct answer. I seem to have a separate issue that I will deal with on my own for now. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171025/discussion-between-johnyl-and-joerdie).